# yii2, kartik, fileinput, You must install 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' extension for Bootstrap

Tags: php, yii2, kartik

Я установил плагин kartik,  подключил и все хорошо, но я получаю ошибку

```
You must install 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' extension for Bootstrap 3.x version support. Dependency to 'yii2-bootstrap' has not been included with 'yii2-krajee-base'. To resolve, you must add 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' to the 'require' section of your application's composer.json file and then run 'composer update'.

NOTE: This dependency change has been done since v2.0 of 'yii2-krajee-base' because only one of 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' OR 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4' OR 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap5' extensions can be installed. The developer can thus choose and control which bootstrap extension library to install.
```

код который я использую

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\file\FileInput;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\Slider */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="slider-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'image[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showUpload' => false,
            'overwriteInitial' => true,
            'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
            'maxFileSize' => 2800
        ],
        'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*'],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "@dev",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "dev-master"
    },
```

у меня установлен bootstrap 4, но не понимаю как исправить эту ошибку

Comment: у вас всё в ошибке написано. перечитайте, и обновите композер и проект

Comment: перечитывал
я обновлял композер, как это обновить проект?

Comment: вам чёрным по белому пишут, что нужно сделать в композере. Делаете то, что просят, дальше соmposer install, и если вылезут ошибки, обновляйте вопрос

Comment: ошибки не вылазят
скорее всего идет конфлитк бутстрапа и слетают стили

Comment: у вас как с английским?

Answer (score 2):

Решается очень легко. Откройте в корневом каталоге проекта config/params.php и добавьте туда в return новую строчку:

'bsVersion' => '4.x',

Остальные комментаторы, для которых "чёрным по белому" пишут, что нужно сделать, не прочитали сообщение об ошибке до конца. В ней дальше указано, что select2 поддерживает работу ИЛИ с bootstrap, ИЛИ с bootstrap4. Если уже стоит bootstrap4, то установка ещё одной версии не поможет - нужно просто явно указать уже установленную версию.

P. S. Да, это тот редкий случай, когда сообщение об ошибке вводит в заблуждение. Сам потратил много времени на решение этой проблемы. Нашёл подсказку [тут](https://demos.krajee.com/bs3/widget-details/select2) в абзаце "Global Bootstrap Version".